# Coefficients of correlation and determination, linear regression

Tags: regression, correlation

The decision-maker has two advisers arguing with each other.

The problem is the following. There is a disease the cause of which is unknown. Some external factors are believed to promote its development. The available funding is distributed between research, countering the external factors, and treatment.

The 1st  adviser has found out that

> some internal random factor X in a human body is highly correlated
>   with the disease risk Y. The coefficient of correlation is
>   r(X,Y)=0.96, r(X,Y)^2=0.92.

He decided though that

> such a high correlation is due to “overwhelming contribution” of one
>   point,

so he took logarithms and got

> r(logX,logY)=0.8, r(logX,logY)^2=0.64.

His conclusion was:

> - A linear correlation between X and Y equal to 0.8 suggests that
>     64% of variation in Y can be explained by X.  Thus the stochastic
>     effects in X appear to be the major contributor to the disease.
> - As we cannot either control or influence factor X the battle against  the disease should be focused mainly on treatment not on the measures
>     against the external factors.

The 2nd adviser objections are:

> - The value 0.8 is the correlation coefficient not between X and Y but between their logarithms; one cannot replace the variables by their logarithms (or by any other functions) while calculating a meaningful characteristic.
> - The "overwhelming" point is not so overwhelming: removing it from consideration changes r from 0.96 to 0.91. Even if it was, taking logarithms is not an appropriate way to deal with outliers while calculating correlation.
> - Correlation doesn’t imply causation so even the true value r=0.96 wouldn’t lead to the conclusion that either X or its stochastic effects are the major contribution to the
>     disease.

The decision-maker has to decide whether the 1st adviser's arguments are a good reason to change funding in favor of treatment by reducing money for measures against the external factors, or it is better to leave everything as it was until more reasonable information appears.

The question is which of advisers is right?

Comment: I've edited my question.